# PayPal-Java-SDK & Google App Engine - Subscription Reflection Error

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, reflection, paypal

I am trying to create a PayPal Subscription on Google App Engine using the PayPal-Java-SDK. I have a slight variation of the code in this [link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sample/src/main/java/com/paypal/api/sample/SubscriptionSample.java) implemented, but I am getting the exception below when calling the Plan.update after creating the PATCH object.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on protected java.lang.String java.net.HttpURLConnection.method
```

After updating the code to use "context.usingGoogleAppEngine(true);", I get a new message:

```
Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
```

So I am assuimg the usingGoogleAppEngine disables the use of Reflection, but still doesn't allow the PATCH operation to occur... which is necessary to change the state of the Payment Plan in PayPal.

Here is the code block:

```
public Plan update(APIContext context, Plan plan) throws PayPalRESTException, IOException 
{
    List<Patch> patchRequestList = new ArrayList<Patch>();
    Map<String, String> value = new HashMap<String, String>();
    value.put("state", "ACTIVE");

    Patch patch = new Patch();

    patch.setPath("/");
    patch.setValue(value);
    patch.setOp("replace");
    patchRequestList.add(patch);

    try{
        plan.update(context, patchRequestList);
    }
    catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
        log.warning("PayPalRESTException!: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("updated. now returning.");

    return plan;
}
```

Lastly, I created an issue in the log with the SDK [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/issues/262)

Comment: I was missing the very obvious "context.usingGoogleAppEngine(true);" method before making the calls. Adding this now makes the program throw another error, which I am now researching: "Invalid HTTP method: PATCH"

Comment: Does the stack trace show the error originating from GoogleAppEngineHttpConnection.java, or DefaultHttpConnection.java? [The Javadoc states](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sdk/src/main/java/com/paypal/base/GoogleAppEngineHttpConnection.java) "In order to activate this feature, set 'http.GoogleAppEngine = true' in the SDK config file", so you may need this extra step to use the correct HttpConnection class on App Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being fixed on January 31, 2017: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/issues/262

Answer (score -1):

I don't see import statement for Patch in your git hub file. Can you please try to import patch from PayPal package.